# Remove part of a input field's value

Tags: jquery, html

I've made a jQuery script, appending/adding to the existing value of an input field. I am doing this by checking if a checkbox is checked, if it is, add text, if it is yet again unchecked, I want to *remove* that text - not clear the entire value, just remove *that* little part of the value - I've tried to do this by replacing the added value with nothing, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my script;

```
$(document).ready(
  function(){
    $('.checkbox').change(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      if($('#output').val().indexOf('?') >= 0) {
        var input = $( "#output" );
        $('#output').val($('#output').val() + '&avatar');
      } else {
        $('#output').val($('#output').val() + '?avatar');
      }
    } else {
      $('#output').val(value.replace('?avatar', ''));
      $('#output').val(value.replace('&avatar', ''));
    }
  });
});
```

I am not the best at jQuery here - I only really do it if I have to, so I might just miss the obvious here.

Here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vws4hpez/) including my HTML as well.

I've been struggling with this here for a while, any help appreciated - thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your fiddle had some error - your div container had class checkbox also, so was causing a double-click.

Also fixed up some other pieces, nothing called value was defined.

https://jsfiddle.net/vws4hpez/1/

```
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $('.checkbox').change(function() {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        console.log('checked');
        if ($('#output').val().indexOf('?') >= 0) {
          var input = $("#output");
          $('#output').val($('#output').val() + '&avatar');
        } else {
          $('#output').val($('#output').val() + '?avatar');
        }
      } else {
        console.log('not');
        $('#output').val($('#output').val().replace('?avatar', ''));
        $('#output').val($('#output').val().replace('&avatar', ''));
      }
    });
  });
```

*HTML:

```
<div class="checkboxDiv">
  <label>
    <input id="avatar" type="checkbox" class="checkbox">Player avatar</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome, I was really just missing the obvious here :) Thank you!